# Android sms notification

Tags: android

i want to remove notification when SMS comes in general inbox. is it possible... if yes then how... i got many site where is metion this is not possible through code...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is proper working code for this 
AndroidManifest.xml register for the receiver

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsFirst" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                </intent-filter>
</receiver>

public class SmsFirst extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final Object SMS_RECEIVED    = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    private static final String TAG          = "SMSBroadcastReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.i(TAG, "Intent recieved: " + intent.getAction());

        if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
            abortBroadcast();
                   }
```

Answer (score 3):

I done this.

Use the abortBroadcast(); in the Receiver.