# How can we access notifications of other application in android?

Tags: android, notifications

Is there are a way to acess the notifications of other applications like 
bluetooth notifications should be opened programatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: get all the notifications by code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030626/android-get-all-the-notifications-by-code)

Answer (score 2):

For detecting missed calls see: [Show Toast on Missed Call in android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667029/show-toast-on-missed-call-in-android-application)

For SMS detection see: [Android sms notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778489/android-sms-notification)

You might also read up in the Android Developer docs on [Intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) (specifically on their use in broadcasting) and [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is not the solution for my issue. I need the generalized solution to open the notifications by passing some paramaters. these are solutions individually,but they don't help me 1%. I have seen these solutions earlier.

Comment: For those downvoting: See his original post before edits; that is what my answer was in response to.